# What does "make no expressed" means?

Tags: american-english, british-english

I've seen this sentence in the books publisher note.

> The authors and publisher have taken care in the preparation of this book, but **make no expressed** or implied warranty of any kind and assume no responsibility for errors or omissions.

What does expressed means in that phrase?

Comment: You need to look at _expressed or implied warranty_ as a whole.

Comment: Expressed as a verb?

Comment: *...make no warranty, expressed or implied.*

Comment: The authors make no expressed warranty of any kind and no implied warranty of any kind.

Answer (score 1):

An express (or "expressed") warranty is a legal term that relates to a verbal or written guarantee. The publisher's note that you're referencing here is simply saying that while the author and publisher have taken reasonable care with the contents of the book, they are making no guarantees to the reader/consumer that it is completely without error or ommission.

Comment: I'd say Past Tense ***expressed*** is [quite simply a ***mistake*** here.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=no+express+warranty%2Cno+expressed+warranty&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cno%20express%20warranty%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cno%20expressed%20warranty%3B%2Cc0) As that linked NGram shows, *no expressed warranty* is virtually unknown by comparison with *no express warranty* (OED sense 3 a *Of a meaning, purpose, stipulation, law, etc.: expressed and not merely implied; definitely formulated; definite, explicit*).

Comment: (The writer is being misled by association with the adjacent term ***implied***.)